# Hide active element and replace it by new on click (javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, hide, element

I have a table with many link-buttons in table head. This buttons work like switchers for the content of the table.
Only one table is displayed at the moment and others are hidden. So if I click button I want to hide current table and show new one.
I use this easy javascript

```
<script>
function hideStuff(element_id) { document.getElementById(element_id).style.display = 'none';}
function showStuff(element_id) { document.getElementById(element_id).style.display = 'block'; }
</script>
```

and onclick event

> onclick="showStuff('table2'); hideStuff('table1');

However I have many buttons there and I dont know, for exapmple I click on table9 button but which table do I need to hide? (Tables 1,2,3...10 coud be active)

So my question is how can I modify my code to hide active element(table) and display new(desired one)

Thank you.

Comment: can you create a fiddle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all your elements the same class, for example `linkButtons`, then you only need one function:

```
function showStuff(element_id) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('linkButtons');
    for (var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById(element_id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way.

markup

```
<div class="nav-bar">
        <a href="#table1">Table 1</a>
        <a href="#table2">Table 2</a>
        <a href="#table3">Table 3</a>
    </div>

    <div id="table1" class="frame">Table 1 content</div>
    <div id="table2" class="frame">Table 2 content</div>
    <div id="table3" class="frame">Table 3 content</div>
```

css

```
.frame {
    display: none;

    &:target {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set a default choice by setting window.location.hash = "#table1" on page load

Comment: And this methodology has many other advantages.                      1) pure css                                                                 2) You can select any menu from anywhere page by setting the hash value (i.e, 'http://www.yoursite.com/sample#table2 opens the page with table2 menu selected)